# CPU Sampling in VS2010 via Attach To Process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, profiling

Is is possible to perform CPU Sampling in VS2010 via the Attach To Process option?  When I do use that option it seems to always default to Memory Profiling.  I can't launch CPU Sampling with the wizard because the ridiculous security software on our work PCs don't allow the DLL injection it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select *Analyze\Profiler\New Performance Session*, the Performance Explorer will open with a new performance session. In the properties of this item, you can specify the type of profiling you want to use:

[image: Performance session properties]

You can then attach this session to your process via "Attach/Detach" in the session's context menu:

[image: Attaching a performance session to a process]

Comment: You can get to CPU Sampling this way?  I'm not at work anymore but I think I tried this and it defaulted to Memory Profiling... I'll find out for sure tomorrow though

Comment: I've added an extra screenshot. I hope it's what you were looking for.