# Attach to process with VS2010 for CPU profiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiling

When profiling an attached process with Visual Studio 2010, I can only get a memory profiling report, no CPU profiling data. I triple-checked that the collection method is "Sampling" and that "Collect .NET object allocation information" is unchecked.

I basically got the same problem as [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823969/cpu-sampling-in-vs2010-via-attach-to-process), but the answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: Check the [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182398%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), focus on step 1 perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something was wrong with the configuration of the environment variables for profiling.

Executing

```
VSPerfCLREnv /sampleon
```

via command line did the trick. Afterwards profiling the CPU worked with the command line tools as well as in Visual Studio.

More details on how to use the profiler from the command line can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985628%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).